# Will the unified API return information about consumer data sources?

Tags: office365

I've been researching the new unified API for office365 (graph.microsoft.com). Currently one can authenticate to it using an organisationalID and it will return information from emails-from-exchange/OneDrive4Business/Skype4Business(future)/calendar-from-exchange/exchange-contacts/etc...

Is there anything on the roadmap to allow one to authenticate using a Microsoft Account and then receive information from the analogous consumer data services email-from-outlook.com/OneDrive/Skype/Outlook.com calendar/outlook.com-contacts/etc

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the O365 unified APIs.  Currently it only supports work/organizational accounts.  However support for consumer accounts (Microsoft Account) is on the roadmap.  We don't have any dates that we can share at present.

Hope this helps,